# JointJS how to dynamically add options to the inspector according to a user input?

Tags: properties, dynamically-generated, jointjs, rappid

```
'bpmn.Gateway': {
    NumberofTrigger : {
        type: 'select',
        options: [
            { value: '0', content: '0' },
            { value: '1', content: '1' },
            { value: '2', content: '2' },
            { value: '3', content: '3' }
        ],
        label: 'Number of Trigger',
        group: 'general',
        index: 1
    },

    ComparisonValue : {
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Comparison Value',
        group: 'general',
        index: 2
    },
    TriggerLogic : {
        type: 'select',
        options: ["Start With",'Contains','End With','Equals','Smaller Than','Greater Than','Not Equals','REGEX','Web Service'],
        label: 'Trigger Logic',
        group: 'general',   
        index: 1
    }
},
```

After I drag a shape out, the inspector table will be shown and the options will be in the `NumberofTrigger` select (in order to select how many triggers option to be selected) and, according to the selected value, the number of set of `TriggerLogic` and `ComparisonValue` will be displayed.

Since I did not find a way to solve this by reading the source code, I would like to know how can this be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question right and you have a finite amount of triggers to be selected, I believe you can simply show more fields by using [`when` expressions with "greater than equal" comparisons (i.e. `gte` primitives)](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.2/ui.html#ui.Inspector.definition-of-expressions), example:

```
'bpmn.Gateway': {
  inputs: {
    attrs: {
      NumberofTrigger : {
        type: 'select',
        options: [
          { value: '0', content: '0' },
          { value: '1', content: '1' },
          { value: '2', content: '2' },
          { value: '3', content: '3' }
        ],
        label: 'Number of Trigger',
        group: 'general',
        index: 1
      },

      ComparisonValue0 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '0'} },
        type: 'text',
        label: 'First Comparison Value',
        // other properties
      },
      TriggerLogic0 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '0'} },
        type: 'select',
        label: 'First Trigger Logic',
        // other properties
      },

      ComparisonValue1 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '1'} },
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Second Comparison Value',
        // other properties
      },
      TriggerLogic1 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '1'} },
        type: 'select',
        label: 'Second Trigger Logic',
        // other properties
      },

      ComparisonValue2 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '2'} },
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Third Comparison Value',
        // other properties
      },
      TriggerLogic2 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '2'} },
        type: 'select',
        label: 'Third Trigger Logic',
        // other properties
      },

      ComparisonValue3 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '3'} },
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Fourth Comparison Value',
        // other properties
      },
      TriggerLogic3 : {
        when: { gte: {'attrs/NumberofTrigger': '3'} },
        type: 'select',
        label: 'Fourth Trigger Logic',
        // other properties
      },
    }
  }
}
```

This is the [main purpose of `when` according to the documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.2/ui.html#ui.Inspector.expressions):

> When an expression is evaluated to `false` (condition is not met) the input using this `when` clause will be **hidden. Otherwise, this input will be shown**.